# Cannot bake any block anymore. Endorsing is fine

Tags: baking

My baker suddenly started to fail injecting every block I bake. I have now missed all the baking slots for a few cycles. It does not seem to be related to the node, since I can endorse blocks perfectly.
I have rebuilt the whole node and database. I have restarted everything. Reinstalled the ledger baking app, which I am using, just in case, but the problem persists.

The baker log on failing blocks shows:

```
Dec 20 02:49:12 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: New baking slot found (level 743393, priority 0) at 2019-12-19T23:50:06-00:00 for xxx after BMCwUEJ7vCHb.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         [339/647]
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: Error while injecting block                      
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:     Included operations : { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0f0d81e72dc03e08bd373d26e0b402911c8d61677f6c9bf04a5a84f39a953017916a1700fa9f30e884eae1fa84e6b1dddcd337fc7714937e999aefc515ecfcc0f" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e07cb2e1c68363a1f5a94044d5614b1eca5b19e89133baf17fab743f49f98173cfa10c41fc7299ab4f20471f3b94e9416f9e50cd6ac4ba34baecff2efa7bbe570a" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e032770757a8685899e6fb29f548ac1b27f473f6641dd33366697c232780e7a834092c40bd99277b22ceb8d87f41c488ba17f9c9d66abb66a4e9941f6c8f47df0c" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0a185a1c85c9b2092dedcb9f74016b93b49246c0b909c17032774a1e11e14f32c42d28f79b09a34629762b367f6fc1e00909c28c72da43838e11f0c5032239747" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":                                                                                                                                    
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0c38068f16d4d298bc1ab632d129177f5312c33541db9eb4f914f20462ec84c39688b0ce9d45d357a0af554fc6e70fc2337ed26e63125752fdf06cc141a92f30f" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e028032196433c446f4514cfa1b5bc38f6c3b777ba6d7b0cf79f340edb143f66c83b4b038a0aecc094af54778184e48ba69fdc2f8e20628986a82c9495c9e08d0e" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e03b4c9ac4e8646bcd69cfe921cd735eb23e79c12087b914eb44dfa12e59a095048c2c4e73321d07d8047b629766e40d571acd6411318ca49f118bd8dd16f7a607" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":                                                                                                                                  
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0f8b3c55bb6fc4a3ba49e93ddb3a81141bd7a1326de9472c4923cf92c27929a8dd33530a106b1a1d6af4eb8b7de3ddb446670426fc893868db61c719c9f045916" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e09b1b20ffc6f281eb960fdd5a04bb565ba5211066c34fa7b611081ff66e7138ce791ea494ae1b83cec8b7895cd2301a1438911f40cf1682fa93452e011474570b" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":                                                                                                                                  
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0021bf73959a16ad13723d4c7337370c7ef0860b25bd65ac5e1b7f459f1277d0d28c9d1b83985aa3b07df41f825991fa7cbf4cbf1ea8e446024937701489b890c" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e07e31e16963f874978e69350fdb3f8706cea379c85efcf26bd9fa4c59be1e07bf4947a30133f37e8a6aad71411441ac8bea833392371960747aca31a0cf5a4201" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",                                       
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0a723a209ed613aa4c2be5ccf9cbcb57c43fcb4c4cd45ec6569189e6b3cf385bd1084e94253e942c4e09adbd67c8a8077789e6644929b076f43dc13c93f2efe00" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0780e823a803434c86d667afdeebac1a71908f16b5d9a6e0e626bcf2ec1d9b73c849997c4c08fa485b3c8f55643b62a809866639fbc8d3313250ba6328b043407" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0d544004df407e41081a9ac4fb34d9aa4bf4d849ca00242f2039e87c3328acc8105c0ee8dc4eb40e918c4110bc3715b3b51906a75a99132933a1913e7259c6801" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":                                                                                                                                  
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e01317357c873b0f6032eec50d7811e8d3651106e4a36baf47c254557b115bb80026cf0ae15108e4546e077ab35a504b8653d2d3f5e14197bead911d78acbd1e08" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e05acc0cf607b3211e9ee385d653edc0b5a77118f26eaba4a7491f432e0d3e6e0324d92147901a55eec9a186a962e47e189043c93a305ea8384fa646cee77a0008" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e08a994296d9ef00bf717f1bca498edfb6c229df6988d7f60edd58185ee93b6e9f65968884731caa0c7c1ce3a3516dd78d8021b5b79df4dac58a03371137bd3d0f" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0283e69a281e5b24d1ff5b42442334bb9ee20f7d36fce18cbd414e33445e390fccd5fb2ce0ad0a4ba44aa0763b903aa610397d74fde92d5b39cf478f77e293d04" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0f02ba83c3f9812d5c5d1cdb33f041aca66fb146f0d0129f1e8b091a1452ae9e78800212e1b6f8ef96ac7183807564395254a056abd159ccb5ceef3d315c9488e" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":                                                                                                                                  
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e089f9f6e3d1914bee2267ce9a3bbc7f1d36f1365c8848fe538c0692566f8499c5d929ee7e4e3a217020670a316738fa32f13b29e17bd18ca198503d80b9d39a0b" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e0dade1ee35e28b655d950c7fc302d5a1902cfb74bba3e4da60b508a559d9b418f16cccd67c456d1ea39a2e0ed7a0c72dbd1a7fde79d14efb6c6ffc7075bf99200" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":                                                                                                                                  
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e02c29e8bcaef453ddc7eaad1fa1a0d9cdf956f33f6199ff396f56b9a6cd9a8bf67d9b6c4700fb19caf3b69f66f317c5cc8d8ae770f6e7dc1b993c64d80ad3b5bc" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMCwUEJ7vCHbg4kRNjtW7UstSLC3ZEGt2jLNwkCdwG2JLgThhq3",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "00000b57e005f081bd913999bcc1f41f09b286925709e0b4dcb11a6e58892b28e00438af1070f2082cb5ae188185ad1da869c32764965374c8eb70c852d3b3647f4d469017" }
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                           { "branch":            
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "BMP1PpbXvx3i7ckh9BZsHm4UPjE7HXtHsor6updc7aHKewTwU1p",
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                             "data":              
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                               "6b0000cfc4e51ea8ab0730ffec4a58ab7cba4b84ec20940ab3fb9f01e85200003ef247eab31bd84f17c4e17d3d9a60fb98c14704d3d7c6c5c06d1e942aa4bd806c0000cfc4e51ea8ab0730ffec4a58ab7cba4b84ec208c0bb4fb9f01e852ac02c090b0030000ca0c7199e178aaafe00726578f0d0e267858aeef00a0e2bd57a68ea8872334bdc2e68ee8fc31d465f24a7f6011a1287fe93529b5cede140c9a790c839f9c14111f74d25da1af5dd0c
f06a889f10baac085ce9a6d0f" }                                                                  
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:     Error, dumping error stack:                  
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:       Ezjsonm.Parse_error(870828711, "JSON.of_buffer expected JSON text (JSON value)")
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:       could not read the block alias file        
Dec 20 02:50:09 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge:                                                  
Dec 20 02:50:51 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 743394 (max_priority = 64)
Dec 20 02:51:51 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 743395 (max_priority = 64)
```

which seems pretty much opaque and useless.

Comment: Can you try to remove the file `block` located in the `.tezos-client` folder ? The logs seems to say that the file is corrupted.

Comment: If just set Pierre's answer as the accepted answer instead of editing the original post, that will suffice your intent and will help others will similar problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opaque yes but useless no: `could not read the block alias file` tells you that the problem is with your file `~/.tezos-client/blocks` (this is the file were is stored the level of the last block baked. It is used as a hight watermark to limit the risk of double baking.)

Deleting it should solve your problem.